# unset all elements of an array and resue it in php

Tags: php, arrays

i used unset method to empty my array it does but when i initilize same array again to reuse it in my code it gives the fatal error

Unsupported operand types

although other unset are working fine but only one array with integer type values have problem.
Any kind of help would be appreciated

here is my piece of code:

```
   <?php

for ($citycount = 0; $citycount < $count; $citycount ++) {
    $loc_qry = "SELECT `ID` as LocationID, `name` as LocationName FROM `territories` where     `formatID` = 43 and `territorylevelID` = 77 and `parentID` = '" . $cityID_arr[$citycount] . "'";
    $loc_qry_res = mysql_query($loc_qry) or die($loc_qry . "<br><br>" . mysql_error());

    while ($rs_loc = mysql_fetch_array($loc_qry_res)) {
        $location_id_arr[] = $rs_loc['LocationID'];
        $location_name_arr [] = $rs_loc['LocationName'];
    }

    $count_loc = count($location_id_arr);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count_loc; $i++) {
        $location_scores = "SELECT ((SUM(sa.achievedScore) /  SUM(sa.totalScore)) * 100) as Score
                                               FROM `scoreanalysis` as sa 
                                               WHERE `formatID` = 43 and `waveID` = '" . $wave_id_arr[0] . "' and `territoryID` = '" . $location_id_arr[$i] . "'";
        $location_scores_res = mysql_query($location_scores);
        while ($res_location_score = mysql_fetch_array($location_scores_res)) {
            $location_scores_arr[] = intval($res_location_score['Score']);
        }
        if ($location_scores_arr[$i] != NULL) {
            $divider = $divider + 1;
        }

        $cityscore = $cityscore + $location_scores_arr[$i];

        //echo $location_id_arr[$i];
        //echo $location_name_arr[$i]."<br>";
    }
    $total = $cityscore / $divider;
    $city_qry = "SELECT `ID` as cityID, `name` as cityName FROM `territories` where  `ID` = '" . $cityID_arr[$citycount] . "'";
    $city_qry_rs = mysql_query($city_qry) or die($city_qry . "<br><br>" . mysql_error());


    while ($city_name = mysql_fetch_array($city_qry_rs)) {
        $cityname = $city_name['cityName'];
    }

    echo $cityname;
    echo intval($total) . "%";
    $total = 0;
    $cityscore = 0;
    unset($location_id_arr);
    unset($location_name_arr);

    $location_id_arr[] = array();
    $location_name_arr[] = array();

    unset($location_scores_arr);
    $location_scores_arr[] = array();

    $city_scores_arr [] = intval($total);
}
```

?>

Comment: Please put code in a block, so it formats in a readable fashion.

Comment: you should consider dumping mysql function for mysqli or PDO

Comment: i think that is another part. what i want to actually do is unset the location_scores array and want to reuse it as location id and location name are used above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[]` syntax is for adding an element to the end of an array; it's not valid for a variable you have just unset. Instead of trying to clear the array at the end of each iteration of the loop, you should be creating a new array at the beginning of each iteration, i.e.:

```
for ($citycount = 0; $citycount< $count; $citycount ++)
{   
    $location_id_arr = array();
    $location_name_arr = array();
    $location_scores_arr = array();

    $loc_qry = "SELECT `ID` as LocationID, `name` as LocationName FROM `territories` where     `formatID` = 43 and `territorylevelID` = 77 and `parentID` = '".$cityID_arr[$citycount]."'";
    $loc_qry_res = mysql_query($loc_qry) or die($loc_qry."<br><br>".mysql_error());
    ...
}
```